# Crash Log in Android : Any Idea

Tags: android

I am new in android and working on a maintenance project
Application crashes if no internet connection while creating Soap Request

Following is screenshot of LogCat, Can any body tell me Whats the reason for crashing.

[image]
[image]

**Amit Battan**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a ANR. It stands for Application Not Resoponding.

Android kills applications which are unresponsive to user interactions. Basically when you are doing heavy processing and the user clicks on a button if your application doesn't respond to the click event within 5 seconds.

In your case, if the internet connection is not there I think your application keeps trying to connect and never comes out of this. Hence the ANR. Consider having a timeout for the request..

Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html) for more details on ANR.

Comment: Thanks .. In my code soap request is calling in the a thread .. but yes its true whenever it gets crash, blockage of UI occurs.... SoapRequest was timeout 3 min , when I reduce it to 10 second the crash become minimize but not solved completely ...

Comment: To resolve that you will need to put your soaprequest into an AsyncTask so it happens in the background and your main UI thread will not be blocked. This way you can resolve it completely.

Answer (score 1):

ANR happens when some long operation takes place in the "main" thread. This is the event loop thread, and if it is busy, Android cannot process any further GUI events in the application, and thus throws up an ANR dialog.

Any task that will take more time should not be performed in the UI thread, and should be moved to either an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread & Handler`.

Check the `/data/anr/traces.txt` file.

Comment: Thanks .. In my code soap request is calling in the a thread .. but yes its true whenever it gets crash, blockage of UI occurs.... SoapRequest was timeout 3 min , when I reduce it to 10 second the crash become minimize but not solved completely ...

Answer (score 1):

put the all the downloading task in a thread and check that once....
Actually android allocates some time to every process if the process does not complete its action in that particular time then ANR error will come.

Comment: Thanks .. In my code soap request is calling in the a thread .. but yes its true whenever it gets crash, blockage of UI occurs.... SoapRequest was timeout 3 min , when I reduce it to 10 second the crash become minimize but not solved completely ...